# How to get values passed to a controller using ajax in code igniter?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, model-view-controller

My javascript function is like this

```
function translate( language ) {            
   var dataString = $("#redirect_url").val(); 
   $.ajax({  
      type: "POST",  
      url: "<?php echo $this->config->base_url()index.php/translate/index/"+language+"/",  
      data: 'url='+dataString,
      success: function(data){
         alert( data );
      }
   });   
   return false;  
}
```

I have used `$this->input->post('url');` but doesn't work. I am getting the post value in firebug. Can anyone help!!!

Comment: Is your controller even being hit?  You can't use PHP code in JS files

Comment: @pattle actually it is'nt js file, the script is in view page

Comment: Do you have crsf protection enabled?

Comment: no @Pattle i have not enabled crsf protection

Comment: Did you try with $_POST['url']? And just check input.php file in core folder is there any thing changed or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({  
    type    : "POST",  
    url     : "<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/translate/index/"+language+"/",  
    data    : {'uristring':dataString},
    success : function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

In your controller you can write:

```
$this->input->post('uristring');
```

Comment: jquery is working but how can i get the post values in controller page?

Comment: Modified the above code please follow up.

Comment: changed the code but not gettting the value using $this->input->post('uristring');

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$.ajax({  
    type    : "POST",  
    url     : "<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/translate/index/"+language+"/",  
    data    : dataString,
    success : function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```